# Emacs Builtin Python Intellisense Support

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, intellisense, completion

Is there any working Intellisense/Completion in Emacs' built-in module `python.el`? If so how do I activate it permantenly?

*Update*:

When I hit `C-M-i` (`completion-at-point`) my Vanilla Emacs errors as

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil)
  buffer-substring-no-properties(nil 243)
  python-shell-completion-at-point(#<process Python>)
  python-completion-at-point()
  completion--capf-wrapper(python-completion-at-point all)
  run-hook-wrapped(completion--capf-wrapper python-completion-at-point all)
  completion-at-point()
  funcall-interactively(completion-at-point)
  call-interactively(completion-at-point nil nil)
  command-execute(completion-at-point)
```

What have I missed?

Comment: What exists before the point when you hit `C-M-i`? Also, there is an Emacs Stack Exchange.

Comment: Looks like you're hitting a bug.  Without knowing more details, such as Emacs version, and specific steps you're taking to reproduce this bug, it's hard to help.

Comment: Nothing happens when I do `C-M-i` in python-mode. Do I have to load the buffer in a python interpreter prior to completion?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's enabled by default.  Just hit TAB when you want completion.  If you want the completion candidates to be suggested in a popup menu without you hitting a special key, you can use `company-mode` from GNU ELPA.

Comment: Don't you really mean M-TAB!? Do you mean `completion-at-point` and/or `complete-symbol`?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend using `elpy` and `autocomplete`, using `jedi` as the backend for code completion.

See [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) and [here](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) for more detail.